# Multiple Tabs conflict with each other

Tags: css, tabs

I have made a tabs navigation with only CSS and it is working! But if i have multiple tab containers in one page then the tab navigations get in conflict with each other.

Down below i have include all code i used and i hope somebody knows a fix for the problem i have.

```css
.tabs-container input {
 display : none;
}

.tabs-container label {
 display : inline-block;
 border : 1px solid transparent;
 margin : 0 0 -1px;
 padding : 5px 15px;
 font-size : 17px;
 font-weight : 600;
 text-align : center;
}

.tabs-container label:hover {
 color : #0094cc;
 cursor : pointer;
}

.tabs-container input:checked + label {
 border : 1px solid #e0dede;
 border-top : 2px solid #0094cc;
 border-bottom : 1px solid #FFFFFF;
 color : #4f4d4d;
}

.tabs-container .content {
 display: none;
 border-top : 1px solid #e0dede;
 border-bottom : 1px solid #e0dede;
}

.tabs-container#tabs1 input#tabs1-01:checked ~ #tabs1-01,
.tabs-container#tabs1 input#tabs1-02:checked ~ #tabs1-02,
.tabs-container#tabs2 input#tabs2-01:checked ~ #tabs2-01,
.tabs-container#tabs2 input#tabs2-02:checked ~ #tabs2-02{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs-container" id="tabs1">
  <input checked="" id="tabs1-01" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tabs1-01">Hier een tab</label>
  <input id="tabs1-02" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tabs1-02">Nog een tab</label>

  <div class="content" id="tabs1-01"><p>Tab 01</p></div>
  <div class="content" id="tabs1-02"><p>Tab 02</p></div>

</div>

<div class="tabs-container" id="tabs2">

  <input checked="" id="tabs2-01" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tabs2-01">Hier een tab</label>
  <input id="tabs2-02" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tabs2-02">Nog een tab</label>

  <div class="content" id="tabs2-01"><p>Tab 01</p></div>
  <div class="content" id="tabs2-02"><p>Tab 02</p></div>

</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by get in conflict with each other? Please explain a bit more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just give your radios for the second set of tabs a different name (radios with the same name can only have one item checked)

```css
.tabs-container input {
 display : none;
}

.tabs-container label {
 display : inline-block;
 border : 1px solid transparent;
 margin : 0 0 -1px;
 padding : 5px 15px;
 font-size : 17px;
 font-weight : 600;
 text-align : center;
}

.tabs-container label:hover {
 color : #0094cc;
 cursor : pointer;
}

.tabs-container input:checked + label {
 border : 1px solid #e0dede;
 border-top : 2px solid #0094cc;
 border-bottom : 1px solid #FFFFFF;
 color : #4f4d4d;
}

.tabs-container .content {
 display: none;
 border-top : 1px solid #e0dede;
 border-bottom : 1px solid #e0dede;
}

.tabs-container#tabs1 input#tabs1-01:checked ~ #tabs1-01,
.tabs-container#tabs1 input#tabs1-02:checked ~ #tabs1-02,
.tabs-container#tabs2 input#tabs2-01:checked ~ #tabs2-01,
.tabs-container#tabs2 input#tabs2-02:checked ~ #tabs2-02{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs-container" id="tabs1">
  <input checked="" id="tabs1-01" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tabs1-01">Hier een tab</label>
  <input id="tabs1-02" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tabs1-02">Nog een tab</label>

  <div class="content" id="tabs1-01"><p>Tab 01</p></div>
  <div class="content" id="tabs1-02"><p>Tab 02</p></div>

</div>

<div class="tabs-container" id="tabs2">

  <input checked="" id="tabs2-01" type="radio" name="tabs2">
  <label for="tabs2-01">Hier een tab</label>
  <input id="tabs2-02" type="radio" name="tabs2">
  <label for="tabs2-02">Nog een tab</label>

  <div class="content" id="tabs2-01"><p>Tab 01</p></div>
  <div class="content" id="tabs2-02"><p>Tab 02</p></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Happens when you stare at the same bit of code for ages, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Check which element is checked in the DOM.

I think you're assuming the elements to be grouped, but this is not the case.
Create button groups (form) to fix this problem.

Comment: You can also check this with Chrome's inspect function (I believe Firefox has this as well). You'll see that the 'checked' attribute switches from one clicked element to the other.